# Как слушать события через socket.io на постороннем сайте?

Tags: socket.io

Есть сайт *site.com/*.
Есть сервер **node.js**.
Как слышать события на *site.com/* через **socket.io**, запустив на своём сервере **node.js**?
Я думаю, должно получиться что-то типа:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io('http://site.com/');
socket.on('connected', function(socket){console.log('ok');});
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NODE.JS**:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://site.com/');
socket.on('connect', function(){console.log('connected!');});
socket.on('event', function(data){console.log('event: ' + data);});
```